# Customize a WCF RIA Services Endpoint

Tags: silverlight-4.0, web-config, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to customize the parameters of a WCF RIA Services endpoint? Specifically, I would like to create a custom binding for the endpoint and increase the `maxReceivedMessageSize` to allow sending the contents of a file that is a few megabytes in size.

I've tried meddling in the web.config, but I'm getting the following error:

> [InvalidOperationException]: The
>   contract name MyNamespace.MyService
>   could not be found in the list of
>   contracts implemented by the service
>   MyNamespace.MyService

### web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="CustomBinaryHttpBinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding />
        <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.MyService" />
      <endpoint address="/binary" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.MyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you weren't getting the error before? Because it seems quite unrelated...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem - we want to send large bitmaps fom Silverlight client to Server using WCF-RIA service invoke operation.

The following change in Web.config worked for us:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="6225920"/>
```

See [How to configure Parameter/Message length for WCF-RIA-Service operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470593/how-to-configure-parameter-message-length-for-wcf-ria-service-operation)